# How to make unlimited count view pager adapter and view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have table to show the data. The user can see the data day by day. I would like to accomplish it by using view pager. The problem is that in view pager, there is limitation for count. I have no idea how to make the unlimited view pager. Is that possible? I would like to hear any suggestion or tutorials.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
final int VIRTUAL_VIEW_COUNT = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return VIRTUAL_VIEW_COUNT;
}
```

Pass the maximum value of integer as the count.

Comment: thanks. Actually I like to swipe the view pager day by day without limitation.

Comment: The getCount() method in view pager adapter returns an integer value, So the max value an integer can store is Integer.MAX_VALUE.